# When writing an array of values to a range, how do I prevent excel from ignoring local date time formats

Tags: excel, vba

I have found many similar questions but never a solution that doesn't include brute force re-engineering.

Using this simple subroutine:

```
Sub readwrite()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    arr = Range("F2:F36").Value
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = CStr(arr(i, 1))
    Next i
    Range("G2:G36").Value = arr
End Sub
```

I get conversion away from my UK locality into US date formats
instead of this:

[image: Correct Date Formats]

I get this:

[image: Incorrect Mixed date formats]

commenting out the Cstr line gets the first result. Adding the line:

```
arr(i, 1) = FormatDateTime(arr(i, 1), 0)
```

after the Cstr line doesn't fix things, nor does using Value2.

I realise that I can fix this with brute force looping, but my real world problem requires an unpredictable mix of dates and blank strings in two out of 32 columns and hundreds of rows, so I need something uncostly.

---

The brute force method is to ensure all conversions from dates to string and back again are done before trying to write out to the sheet:

```
        arr(i, 1) = Format(arr(i, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
        arr(i, 1) = DateValue(arr(i, 1)) + TimeValue(arr(i, 1))
```

As I said, this is do-able and works, it's just a bit problematic.

---

I'd appreciate any advice. I'm a software tester by trade but also a fairly advanced coder.

addendum - I put =G2-F2 in column H and got:
[image: real differences in date]
Which means this date handling bug has real consequences.

Comment: Don't understand what you want. Can you add some colors/indications to your screenshots ?

Comment: Sorry Patrick - not sure how that would help. I want the change to US formats to not happen as they are wrong.

Comment: I think the coloring is so that we can see where you are having a problem.  The two pictures seem, on the surface, to be the same. Also, what are your Windows Regional Settings?  and are the Dates in the Date column text? or "real Dates"?

Comment: they were different when I looked at them

Comment: corrected the image

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your comments. Windows is UK regional settings everywhere, and the dates column is a formula, creating dates from numbers using =Date(y,m,d)+time(h,m)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by ensuring the array held date objects (where necessary) when it was written out to the sheet. This meant ensuring that every final assignment of a date object to the array used

```
myarray(x,y) = datevalue(mydate)+timevalue(mydate)
```

because even though mydate was a date object, assigning it to the array in any other way converted it back to a string!

I had an ancillary issue in that I was using

```
myrange.value = Application.Transpose(myarray)
```

and the Transpose function converted the date objects to string objects again, which were then misinterpreted by the value assignment. I wrote and used my own transpose function instead.

It would have been simpler for me if Microsoft could fix the bug in value assignment and assume local formats when dealing with ambiguous date strings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I removed the Application.Transpose statements from my code and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Change the NumberFormat of the Range prior to writing the values of the Array to the Range.</strike>

[Range.NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)

[NumberFormat Codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

```
Range("G2:G36").NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy hh:mm"
```

I never use copy and paste in my macros, but an "alternative method" to "Brute Force" would be:

```
Range("F2:F36").Copy
Range("G2:G36").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: also manually changing the cell format to custom dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm after the fact makes no difference

Comment: @SimonOliver What displays when you run
    `Debug.Print CDbl(arr(i, 2))`

Comment: The date as originally written - the issue is definitely in the range.value assignment - VBA assumes it is a non-local US date by default and converts it without a by-your-leave. It even happens with a single cells(x,y).value assignment

Comment: @SimonOliver So, if you format F3 as a Number, does it display 43832.50?

Comment: the underlying number values were changed by the range assignment - see my solution in the edit - I think I can live with the brute force method of making it a date object again before assigning it to the range.

Comment: Thanks Strithken, but that prevents data processing between the copy and paste - putting the range values into an array which can then be written directly back to a range is the objective.